# When I run bitcoind, it does not generate logs

Tags: bitcoind

When I run bitcoind on a bitcoin cash node, no logs are generated.
What do I need to do to get this thing logging?

This is my run command. 
`./bitcoind -daemon -conf=/data/bitcoin/bitcoin.conf -pid=/data/bitcoin/bitcoin.pid -debuglogfile=/data/logfile.log`

This is my config.

```
                server=1
                txindex=1
                zmqpubrawtx=tcp://0.0.0.0:28332
                zmqpubhashblock=tcp://0.0.0.0:28332
                rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
                rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0
                rpcuser=xxx
                rpcpassword=yyy
                rpcbind=0.0.0.0
                rest=1
                daemon=1
                datadir=/data/bitcoin
                rpcworkqueue=128
                whitelist=0.0.0.0/0
                rpcallowip=::/0
                printtoconsole=1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to remove `printtoconsole=1` from the config. You can specify the log path with `-debuglogfile`.

Comment: If you don't specify a log path, logs will be stored in the `datadir` directory—look for a file named `debug.log`